# How can I trigger the same function from multiple events with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

Is there a way to have `keyup`, `keypress`, `blur`, and `change` events call the same function in one line or do I have to do them separately?

The problem I have is that I need to validate some data with a db lookup and would like to make sure validation is not missed in any case, whether it is typed or pasted into the box.

Answer (score 2058, accepted):

You can use `.on()` to bind a function to multiple events:

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event fired
});
```

Or just pass the function as the parameter to normal event functions:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   ...
}

$('#element')
    .keyup(myFunction)
    .keypress(myFunction)
    .blur(myFunction)
    .change(myFunction)
```

Comment: With space separated events how do you also include name spacing? `.on('keyup.foo keypress.foo blur.foo change.foo', …)` or `.on('keyup keypress blur change .foo', …)`?

Comment: Problem with this is that myFunction will probably get called multiple times, which you might want to prevent.

Comment: How can I pass parameter in this function?

Comment: @Esger Anyway to do this? In mobile, I always need to `on('click tap', e => {...})`. The listener may be triggered twice, I just wanna trigger once, how can I code in the listener function?

Comment: @Tomlsion Maybe add a className 'busy' to the element in the called function, and then `$('#element:not(.busy)').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e){…});` Finally remove the className 'busy'.

Comment: @kushalvm you define an anonymous function that calls the function with arguments: `$("#element").change(function(){myFunction(param1, param2)})`

Comment: In answer to @TomIsion's question of two years ago (for future readers): There is, `$('#element").one('click tap', e => {…})` that, if I read the docs right, executes the code once per event type.

Comment: @DaveLand I tried with `$(document).one('ajaxSuccess ajaxComplete', function()` and it triggered twice...

Comment: This wont work on a different element, meaning you will not be able to use this method if you want  << $('#elementXX').on('click') >>  to reuse the function

Comment: Some modification `$( document ).on( 'keyup keypress blur change', 'input[name="some_name"]', myFunction ); ` But, yes, the function starts multiple times.

Answer (score 70):

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the `.bind()` method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout',".brand", function () {
  $(".star").toggleClass("hovered");
})
```

Comment: This is done for a delegated event, it will work, but it's not the simplest way of doing it, nor the most efficient.

Comment: Event delegation is important, and may (or may not) be required depending on when the script is loaded / run, and if the elements exist in the DOM at the time the script is loaded / run.

Answer (score 61):

I was looking for a way to get the event type when jQuery listens for several events at once, and Google put me here.

So, for those interested, `event.type` is my answer :

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(event) {
    alert(event.type); // keyup OR keypress OR blur OR change
});
```

More info in the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/).

Comment: What if I want to use and between events instead of or. So that if both events occur then trigger this function?

Answer (score 27):

You can use [bind method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach function to several events. Just pass the event names and the handler function as in this code:

```
$('#foo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});
```

Another option is to use chaining support of jquery api.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 24):

> Is there a way to have `keyup`, `keypress`, `blur`, and `change` events call the same function in one line?

It's possible using `.on()`, which accepts the following structure: `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`, so you can pass multiple events to this method. In your case it should look like this:

```
$('#target').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
    // "e" is an event, you can detect the type of event using "e.type"
});
```

And here is the live example:

```js
$('#target').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
  console.log(`"${e.type.toUpperCase()}" event happened`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="target">
```

Answer (score 18):

If you attach the same event handler to several events, you often run into the issue of more than one of them firing at once (e.g. user presses tab after editing; keydown, change, and blur might all fire).

It sounds like what you actually want is something like this:

```
$('#ValidatedInput').keydown(function(evt) {
  // If enter is pressed
  if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    // If changes have been made to the input's value, 
    //  blur() will result in a change event being fired.
    this.blur();
  }
});

$('#ValidatedInput').change(function(evt) {
  var valueToValidate = this.value;

  // Your validation callback/logic here.
});
```

Answer (score 15):

This is how i do it.

```
$("input[name='title']").on({
    "change keyup": function(e) {
        var slug = $(this).val().split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase();
        $("input[name='slug']").val(slug);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 13):

You could define the function that you would like to reuse as below:

```
var foo = function() {...}
```

And later you can set however many event listeners you want on your object to trigger that function using on('event') leaving a space in between as shown below:

```
$('#selector').on('keyup keypress blur change paste cut', foo);
```

Comment: Generally you should explain your answer. Simply pasting code does nothing to help the OP understand their problem or your solution.

Comment: what if I need first argument in jquery event subscriber function (event)? How to use it?

Comment: That's ok, you can just declare the function with the event parameter and then access it from within the method. These events will pass the object in themselves. I hope this helps.


var foo = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

$('#selector').on('keyup keypress blur change paste cut', foo);

Answer (score 7):

The answer by Tatu is how I would intuitively do it, but I have experienced some problems in Internet Explorer with this way of nesting/binding the events, even though it is done through the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

I havn't been able to pinpoint exactly which versions of jQuery this is the problem with. But I sometimes see the problem in the following versions:

- 2.0.2
- 1.10.1
- 1.6.4
- Mobile 1.3.0b1
- Mobile 1.4.2
- Mobile 1.2.0

My workaround have been to first define the function,

```
function myFunction() {
    ...
}
```

and then handle the events individually

```
// Call individually due to IE not handling binds properly
$(window).on("scroll", myFunction);
$(window).on("resize", myFunction);
```

This is not the prettiest solution, but it works for me, and I thought I would put it out there to help others that might stumble upon this issue

Answer (score 7):

```
$("element").on("event1 event2 event..n", function() {
   //execution
});
```

[This tutorial](http://www.jquerypro.com/blog/trigger-jquery-multiple-events-with-one-function/) is about handling multiple events.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple to implement this with the built-in DOM methods without a big library like jQuery, if you want, it just takes a bit more code - iterate over an array of event names, and add a listener for each:

```
function validate(event) {
  // ...
}

const element = document.querySelector('#element');
['keyup', 'keypress', 'blur', 'change'].forEach((eventName) => {
  element.addEventListener(eventName, validate);
});
```

If you'd want to mimic adding to more than 1 element:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.commonSelector');
['keyup', 'keypress', 'blur', 'change'].forEach((eventName) => {
  elements.forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, validate);
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that **jQuery does *nothing less*** - in the end it itself goes down to `return elem.each( function() { jQuery.event.add( this, types, fn, data, selector ); } );` ([this is straight from jQuery 3.6.0 code](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js))

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event fired
});
```

You can use:

```
$('#element').on('input', function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event fired
});
```

`input` is trigerred for `keyup` `keypress` `blur` `change` events even for `paste`!

Answer (score 0):

But to prevent multiple triggering:

```
var a;
var foo = function() {
    clearTimeout(a);
    a=setTimeout(function(){
        //your code
        console.log("Runned")
    },50);
}
$('textarea').on('blur change', foo);
```