# JQuery set the same event for several selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

As opposed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function) question, here I am asking if it's possible to do something like this:

```
$(several different selectors).click(function() {
    console.log("Click");
});
```

So if I have something like this:

```
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
```

I want to make `several different selectors` select `#a`, `#b` and `#c`, and then whichever one I click would log "Click". I tried `$('#a', "#b", "#c")` and it doesn't work; can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass it *one* string, [with the selectors separated by a comma](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('#a, #b, #c').click(function() {
    console.log("Click");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try this, as i have tried this and it worked for me

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#a, #b, #c').click(function () { 
        console.log("Click"); 
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt was very close. [Here is the documentation multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Your selector should be `$("#a, #b, #c")`