# How To Handling Multiple Events On jQuery

Tags: jquery

i want to handling multiple events in one event function. i used jquery ".on" function but it doesn't worked for multiple events. on the following code doesn't work:

```
$("input.action:checkbox").on('click,change',function(){
    alert('bla bla');
});
```

When clicked or changed any item on this selector i want fire to the same function. but i dont want to in another function handling. as can be seen following example code i dont want:

```
    $("input.action:checkbox").on('click',function(){
        changePlease(); // in this func will process 
    });

  $("input.action:checkbox").on('change',function(){
      changePlease(); // in this func will process 
    });
```

have u got any idea?

Comment: you shouldn't have to bind click event on a checkbox, only change handler is enough

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is correct ,but a small syntax issue,Just remove comma between the `event` names ..

```
$("input.action:checkbox").on('keyup keypress blur change',function(){
    alert('bla bla');
});
```

[And more possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Comment: @Mesuti Thankyou glad to help you.Mark it as answer(green tick) if you found this answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, best way is:

```
$("input[type=checkbox].action").on('click change',changePlease);
```

Just use the name of function as callback, without '()'. BTW, using `input[type=checkbox]` improve selector performance.

Comment: like i said in comment, you should just use onchange event, click is useless here for checkbox