# Handle multiple events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Can I turn this:

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(){
    n = 1;
});  

$(document).bind("mouseup", function(){
    n = 2;
});  

$(document).bind("mousemove", function(){
    n = 3;
});
```

Into something like this:

```
$(document).bind("mousemove mouseup mousedown", function(e){
    if (e.event == mousemove){
        n = 3;
    }
});
```

<s>Adding more text because stackoverflow says my post contains mostly code</s>

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function (nearly the same problem)

Comment: One slight suggestion is to use a lookup to avoid an if - `n = ({mousedown: 1, mouseup: 2, ..})[e.type];` Or, another option is to just keep the non-numeric names as strings (which I find more clear than numbers :>) ..

Comment: @user2246674 i don't think he actually meant n=1,2,3 probably a pseudo code OP posted.

Comment: @PSL You're probably correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.type` in your case `e.type` to determine what event it is.

```
$(document).bind("mousemove mouseup mousedown", function(e){
    if (e.type== "mousemove"){
        n = 3;
    }...
});
```

In your case `e` is already an `event` so there is no property called event on `e`

Comment: e.type instead of e.event ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of trying to do this, with if statements to check the event:

```
$(document).bind("mousemove mouseup mousedown", function(e){
    if (e.type == mousemove){
        n = 3;
    } else if {
        //some code
    } ...   
});
```

You could simply:

```
$( document ).bind({
       mousemove: function() {
       n = 3;
    },
       mouseup: function() {
       // Do something on mouseup
    },
       mousedown: function() {
       // Do something on mousedown
    }

});
```

Code is much cleaner and it should perform faster.

As shown on the JQuery API Documentation.
http://api.jquery.com/bind/#multiple-events