# Multiple events at once?

Tags: jquery

Is there any simple way of doing :

```
var doSomeWork = function(){
    //Do some work...
}

$('#myDomElement').on({
    mouseenter : doSomeWork(),
    mousemove :  doSomeWork(),
    mouseleave : doSomeWork(),
    mouseup : doSomeWork(),
    mousedown : doSomeWork()
})
```

I didn't like this repetitious style. Maybe something similar to:

```
$('#myDomElement').on(['mouseenter', 'mousemove', 'mouseleave', 'mouseup', 'mousedown '],function(){
    doSomeWork(),
})
```

Is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: `$('#myDomElement').on('mouseenter mousemove mouseleave mouseup mousedown',doSomeWork);`

Comment: First post on google. for the keyword "multiple events jquery".. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2534089/1577396)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind multiple events using `.on()`  as follows

```
$('#myDomElement').on('mouseenter mousemove mouseleave mouseup mousedown',function(){
    doSomeWork(),
})
```

Separate multiple events by just using a space