# JQuery same functionality on event, different handlers and elements

Tags: jquery

I've got lots of text inputs that have this event:

```
$('.textBoxSal').live('keyup', function () {...});
```

I have also drop down list with a different `class` that I want it to make the same code ,
my question is :

can I add somehow my `dropdownlist` to this event, but with other (`onchange`) event?

Comment: `$('.differentClass').live('onchange', function(){..add the code from above function here});`

Comment: Can't you define a named function containing that code before-hand?

Comment: live is deprecated use on instead https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: my question was if I can overload events with different class name and different functionallity in the same handler

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  It's a small piece of code to add if you abstract your function to a named function as @oGeez mentioned.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function