# Pass object to jQuery.on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I read somewhere that it is possible to do something like this:

```
$(document).on({click: function(){}})
```

Is this true or is there something similar to this that jQuery supports? I would like to pass an object with settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is an easy way to bind more than one event at once, like this:

```
$(target).on({
    click: function() { /*... do something when user clicks ...*/ },
    mouseover: function() { /*... do something else ...*/ },
    keyup: function(){ /* ... */ }
    // and so on...
});
```

You can even do this to bind a function to multiple events:

```
$(target).on('click mouseover keyup', function() { 
    // something to handle all events... 
});
```

**See  [.on() documentation on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: related [Passing multiple events to trigger same function jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)