# How to stack a key event and a click event from two different elements to trigger the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to combine both an `click` event from an `img` element and a `onkeypress` event from an input element to trigger the same function?.  This is what I got so far and it only services the click event...

> ```
>   <div class="dataLine2">
>         <img id ="daysText" src="images/days.png">
>         <img class ="days" src="images/1day.png">
>         <img class ="days" src="images/2days.png">
>         <img class ="days" src="images/3days.png">
>         <img class ="days" src="images/4days.png">
>     </div>
> ```

```
    <input type="text" class="stateInput" placeholder="State" maxlength="2"  value="NY" onkeypress="myFunction(???)" />

    <script> 
        //  I suspect that jQuery can stack two triggers in some daisy chain, but it eludes me...
        $('.days').on('click', function (e){
            // Do somehting crazy with the "e" being critical to the process in this function
            // 
        }
    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Dennis

Comment: You mean, using the same handler on click and keypress? This is not stacking.

Comment: @Artjom Yes!  Are you saying Impossible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Comment: It's perfectly possible by defining the function which could handle both types of events and pass this function to `$days.on("click", func);` and  `$input.on("keypress", func);`

Comment: The trouble is that I need the (event) to identify who did what!

Comment: You can find out the event type with the incoming event variable ... ```$('.days').on('keypress click', 
function(event) {
    alert(event.type); // keypress or click
});```

Answer (score 1):

Just write your handler function and assign it:

```
    function foo(e) {
        // do something
    }

    $('.days').on('click', foo);
    $('input').on('keypress', foo);
```

Comment: The outcome, however is grim...  It looks good and seems to make sense, but in reality, when the click is fired, occasionally the keypress follows suit and I get some bad results.  It took me lots of time to figure this out.  It is some form of cross pollination between the events.  Thanks any way...

Answer (score 0):

I was ducked 2 points for posting this question which purportedly is not original.  Unfortunately, the other question/solution does not concern the same idea.

The unanimous solution for the other problem was:

```
`$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(event) {`
```

**That is useless to me.** In my setting I am not firing from the same element.  I have 5 different elements each of which sends a trigger to the same function.  And that is clearly stated in my post AND in the title!!!

So I should receive my 2 points back and then allow other points to pile on because I asked an original question, which has not yet been answered.

DK