# Get click & double-click working using jquery.finger

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to use double-click of jquery.finger plugin for mobile, but also want to support standard desktop click.  Is this possible, anyone? or @ngryman

Simple example:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <i></i>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>

$('#mydiv').on('doubletap', function() {
  // do something in both desktop & mobile
});
```

Currently, in desktop, a single click doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ngryman - would love to hear your suggestion on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#mydiv').on('doubletap click', function(e) {

  // do something in both desktop & mobile
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Will that cause any bubbling problems or it being called twice?

Comment: @parti You can make sure it doesn't by stopping the propagation.

Comment: I wanted doubletap in mobile & single click in desktop.  Do I just change dblclick to click ?

Comment: @parti Yes, you would just change dblclick to click