# JQuery same event for two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have one jquery event for two elements, 1 textbox and 1 select option.

```
$('#txtInput').keyup(function() {
    some_function();
});

$('#sltInput').change(function() {
    some_function();
});
```

But i wan't something like:

```
$('#txtInput').keyup('#sltInput').change(function() {
   some_function();
});
```

Can do it?

Comment: What you're asking for is called [research](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#multiple-events) and you have not done yours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate multiple events, on multiple elements.

```
$('form').on('keyup change', '#sltInput, #txtInput'), function(){

});
```

[And the associated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4Lgx27q/)