# Multiple Events to trigger a single function in Chrome Bookmarks API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome Extension that has to deal with Bookmarks.
I want multiple (4) events

```
onCreated
onRemoved
onChanged
onMoved
```

to perform a single function
How do I it?
Reference https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#event-onChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not a very good idea if you want to use the information passed from those events (it's different for every event), but you *can* do it. Just make a non-anonymous handler and register it for every event:

```
function universalHandler(a,b) {
  // Do stuff
}

chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(universalHandler);
chrome.bookmarks.onRemoved.addListener(universalHandler);
chrome.bookmarks.onChanged.addListener(universalHandler);
chrome.bookmarks.onMoved.addListener(universalHandler);
```

Comment: Can't I do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Comment: I am not using the information passed from events. I want to backup all bookmarks to Google Drive whenever any of these events occur.

Comment: No, you can't do the same as in jQuery. But the end result does not differ.