# HTML multiple events to trigger the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to have multiple events (*e.g. oninput, onblur*) trigger exactly the same function in the HTML?

This is the HTML that I'm trying to simplify:

```
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" oninput="toggleSuccessIcon(this, isEmail)" onblur="toggleSuccessIcon(this, isEmail)">
```

I know this is possible in jQuery as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function), but since I have a lot of different inputs (*e.g. address, postcode, etc.*) that need to call different functions (e.g. *toggleSuccessIcon(this, isAddresss), toggleSuccessIcon(this, isPostCode), etc.*) I wanted to avoid having a long and messy initialisation in the JavaScript. However, if I am being foolish by doing this in HTML rather than JQuery I'd appreciate an explanation as to the advantage of using JQuery.

Note that *isEmail*, *isAddress*, *isPostCode*, etc. is a function name.

Comment: i belive its a bigger mess to mix js with html

Comment: You can attach events through `addEventListener` in JavaScript or in much cleaner way using jQuery.

Comment: All the inputs actually use "toggleSuccessIcon", but the second and optional third parameter varies from input to input, e.g. <input id="Address" name="Address" type="text" oninput="toggleSuccessIcon(this, hasContent, 5)" onblur="toggleSuccessIcon(this, hasContent, 5)">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a helper function

```
// events and args should be of type Array
function addMultipleListeners(element,events,handler,useCapture,args){
  if (!(events instanceof Array)){
    throw 'addMultipleListeners: '+
          'please supply an array of eventstrings '+
          '(like ["onblur","oninput"])';
  }
  //create a wrapper for to be able to use additional arguments
  var handlerFn = function(e){
    handler.apply(this, args && args instanceof Array ? args : []);
  }
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i+=1){
    element.addEventListener(events[i],handlerFn,useCapture);
  }
}

function handler(e) {
  // do things
};

// usage
addMultipleListeners(document.getElementById('Email'),
                     ['oninput','onblur'],handler,false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data` as:

```
<input class="configurable-events" type="text" data-events="blur focus click" data-function="myFunction" />
<input class="configurable-events" type="password" data-events="blur focus" data-function="myPasswordFunction" />
```

in jQuery you can use something like:

```
$('.configurable-events').each(function(){
    $(this).on($(this).data('events'), function(){
      $(this).data('function')($(this));
    });
});

function myFunction(myInput) {
  console.log(myInput.value());
}

function myPasswordFunction(myPasswordInput) {
  console.log(myPasswordInput.size());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input").on( "click blur", toggleSuccessIcon(this, isEmail));
```

Comment: This would be great if I wanted to add the same function to all inputs, however the second parameter of toggleSuccessIcon is a input field dependent parameter.

Comment: The answer only depends on what you asked.If you want to change it for this input field only, then make $("#isEmail") instead of $("input").I dont get what you actually mean by isEmail as the second parameter.You will always get the id from the selector by using $(this).attr('id').

Answer (score 1):

I know this is so massively late, but I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring anyway. When I have numerous events that need to trigger the same thing, it feels so wasteful to do 3-5 eventListeners, so what I do is making a forEach-loop on an array that holds the event-names in vanilla JS. I wish though, that the eventListener could accept an array as a name directly, but here we are.

```
    const element = document.getElementById('Email');

    ['input', 'blur'].forEach(eventName =>{
        element.addEventListener(eventName, event=>{
            // Your eventcode goes here.
        });
    });
```