# Multiple events in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have multiple events in jQuery, like this?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#page-wrapper').css('height', (window.innerHeight - 51) + 'px');
});
```

Now it's just `resize()` but is it possible to make it so that it is on both `resize` and `ready`?

```
$(window).resize.ready(function () {
    $('#page-wrapper').css('height', (window.innerHeight - 51) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Comment: @JonathanAnctil - except in this case, the `ready` event is on the `document` object and the `resize` event is on the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is done like this by just triggering a resize event when the document is ready which will then call your normal resize handler:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#page-wrapper').css('height', (window.innerHeight - 51) + 'px');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // trigger a resize event when the document is ready
    $(window).resize();
});
```

See the third form of `.resize()` in the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).  If it is called without any arguments, then it triggers the resize event so existing event handlers are called.