# .on("hover", ...) chaining not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file that has .on("click" , ..) chaining happening that I would like to also add a hover event to. My code is:

```
}).on('hover' , '.tooltip' , function (e) {
   if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
      var tip = $(this).attr('title');
      var tipTemp = $(this).attr('data-title', tip);
      $('#tooltip').remove();
      $(this).parent().append('<div id="tooltip">' + tipTemp + '</div>');
      $(this).removeAttr('title');      
      $('#tooltip').fadeIn(300);
    }else{
      $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));
      $('#tooltip').fadeOut(300);
      $(this).removeAttr('data-title');
    }
});
```

I understand that I can really only pass one function this way so I am checking for the event type to trigger the appropriate behavior. This doesn't seem to be working for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: you can try .on('click hover mouseover', function(e))

Comment: `.hover` is just shorthand for `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`.

Comment: hover isn't a DOM event.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
}).on('mouseenter' , '.tooltip' , function (e) {
    var tip = $(this).attr('title');
    var tipTemp = $(this).attr('data-title', tip);
    $('#tooltip').remove();
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="tooltip">' + tipTemp + '</div>');
    $(this).removeAttr('title');      
    $('#tooltip').fadeIn(300);
});

}).on('mouseleave' , '.tooltip' , function (e) {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));
    $('#tooltip').fadeOut(300);
    $(this).removeAttr('data-title');
});
```

Comment: This did it. Dipak's solution probably would work too but I wanted to uphold the chaining in the code. N0ir's suggestion did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind several event handlers at once. In your case it will be:

```
.on('mouseenter mouseleave' , '.tooltip' , function (e) { ... });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if (e.type == "mouseenter") {`

And `hover` is not a valid method to use with `.on()` - I am not sure about this though.. use `mouseover` or `mouseenter`

Use it as:

```
$('.tooltip-holder').on('mouseover' , '.tooltip' , function () {
      var tip = $(this).attr('title');
      var tipTemp = $(this).attr('data-title', tip);
      $('#tooltip').remove();
      $(this).parent().append('<div id="tooltip">' + tipTemp + '</div>');
      $(this).removeAttr('title');      
      $('#tooltip').fadeIn(300);      
});

$('.tooltip-holder').on('mouseout' , '.tooltip' , function () {
      $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));
      $('#tooltip').fadeOut(300);
      $(this).removeAttr('data-title');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuaw51dL/)

Answer (score 0):

As per [jQuery source code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js), `hover` is not included in the event list that triggered leading to JQuery `.on()` because `.hover()` is just a shortcut for JQuery `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`. So, in short, you **cannot** use `hover` with `.on()` like below:

```
}).on('hover' , '.tooltip' , function (e) {...
```

So, your option is to use `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` like below:

```
.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    }
}, '.tooltip');
```