# jQuery: .on() using events in a plain object to reference one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find the presentation/style of the following jQuery .on() preferable (ie handing over a plain object that can contain multiple events/callbacks):

```
$( selector ).on( {  mouseover:function(event) {
                       console.log('mouseover');
                     },
                     mouseout:function(event) {
                       console.log('mouseout');
                     }
                   });
```

However I would like both mouseover and focus to reference the same function so I tried the following:

```
$( selector ).on( {  'mouseover, focus':function(event) {
                       console.log('over/focus');
                     },
                     'mouseout, focusout':function(event) {
                       console.log('mouseout/focusout');
                     }
                   });
```

The results were focus and focusout worked but not mouseover/mouseout.

Could anyone guide me on how to do this inside a plain object, ie with this structure/style of using .on()

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Comment: Thank you for your negative contribution. The key difference in my question was simply the events and handling all being contained in a plain object and 'possible duplication' differs from that. However I accept the string containing the events with a space and not a comma resolves the issue.

Comment: @user2190690: There's no need to have a go at Fuiba. Yes, there's a difference in the question, but it was a reasonable question to point to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. I'm not having a go a Fuiba. I'm sure he's an awesome person, and clearly more clued up at jQuery than me :-) The response was an ironic gesture of humour that may not have been read as such...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data):

> An object in which the string keys represent **one or more space-separated event types** and optional namespaces, and the values represent a handler function to be called for the event(s).

*(my emphasis)*

So lose the commas:

```
$( selector ).on( {  'mouseover focus':function(event) {
// No comma -------------------^
                       console.log('over/focus');
                     },
                     'mouseout focusout':function(event) {
// No comma ------------------^
                       console.log('mouseout/focusout');
                     }
                   });
```

Or of course, use named functions.

Here's an example using events that are unrelated to each other (for clarity):

```js
$("#the-element").on({
  "change click": function(e) {
    $("<p>").text("Got " + e.type).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="the-element">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```