# how to apply hover and click event at the same time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to apply hover and click event at the same time. my `hover()` is working perfectly but when i clicks on the `div` it don't shows anything ... i was watching examples on stackoverflow but didn't found. i want when i clicks on the `div` it show me the same behaviour as it showing me on `hover()`

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gt70233f/

myHTML

```
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="majic">
        <img src="http://www.endlessicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/magic-icon-614x460.png" style="height:80px; width:80px;">
        <h4>WEB APPLICATIONS</h4>
      </div>
```

my JS

```
  function hoveronImage(id,imageonhover,imageonhoverout){

    $(id).on('mouseover',function(){

     $(this).children('img').attr('src','http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcon test/vintage/256/Magic-Wand-icon.png')
     .next('h4').css({
     'color':'#eab000 '

     });

   });

   $(id).on('mouseout',function(){

    $(this).children('img').attr('src','http://www.endlessicons.com/wp-  content/uploads/2013/02/magic-icon-614x460.png')
    .next('h4').css({
    'color':'#404040'
    });

   });

   }

   hoveronImage('#majic','hovermajic','majic');
```

i was trying

```
    $(id).on('mouseover click',function(){

     $(this).children('img').attr('src','http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcon test/vintage/256/Magic-Wand-icon.png')
     .next('h4').css({
     'color':'#eab000 '

     });

   });
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense... the effect you want is happening on hover, why would you want to re-apply the same effect on click? You can only click on an item when the mouse is hovering over it anyway?

Comment: i edit the question please take a look

Comment: Why do you need a `click` handler? Like @AdamJeffers said, in order to click something, you have to hover over it first, so the click handler is redundant.

Comment: Still don't understand why you would want to do this for the same reasons I've already explained... however this may provide you with some help??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Comment: actually i making a text carousel . and when i hover over div i want the image and heading color to be changed . which is working perfectly . but i also want when i click the div i want to make the 2nd image replace to first image and also heading color . so in this sense my current div will be active as you normally sees in text or image carousel

Answer (score 1):

I've never needed to do this before but knowing jQuery this should work:

```
$(id).on('mouseover', function(){
   //cool stuff here
}).on('click', function(){
   //other cool stuff here
});
```

If it's the same action (which it seems like it is) then assign to a named function.

```
function coolStuff(){
    //cool stuff here
};

$(id).on('mouseover', coolStuff).on('click', coolStuff);
```

Of course, since the action is firing on mouseover first, if you aren't incrementing changes on each event, you probably won't see any difference on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by simply using :hover and click.

Use a css like

```
div#majic > h4{
color: "#404040";
}

div#majic > h4:hover, div#majic > h4.majichover{
color:"#eab000";
}
```

Then in your like add the "magichover" class to h4