# jQuery same function for multiple events, each event targeting different elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'd like to accomplish what is being done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2534107/2951835) except with one twist:
I want each event to target different elements.

The use case is a select box that should fire an event if anything but the first "choose your option" option is selected

```
$(document).on('change', 'select:nth-child(1)', function(e) ){
  do_stuff();
});


$(document).on('click', 'select:not(:first-child)', function(e) ){                         
  do_stuff();
});
```

Is there a combined, cleaner way to do this, without having to create `do_stuff()`?

How can this be done without the event firing twice?

Comment: Inspect the target in the handler.

Comment: what is the purpose of the first event on there? seems the second one will fire on all events except the first one already...

Comment: @oMiKeY in my code, i have a swatch that triggers a dropdown selection change as well. But I don't want it to do stuff if the first option is selected. I also have code existing in the 'change' event. The portion relies on state variables that i'd like to have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an answer but you could also use some combination of this:

NOTE: tab to the element on the page to trigger the `focusin` event

```
$('#selectcontainer').on('change focusin manual', ".myselectthing", function(e) {
  var selectionIndex = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
  $('#results').text("this type " + e.type + ":" + $(this).val() + " : " + selectionIndex);
});

$('#selectcontainer').find('.myselectthing').val("ralf").trigger("manual");
```

Some sample markup:

```
<div id="results">
  empty
</div>
<div id="selectcontainer">
  <select class="myselectthing">
    <option value="me">choose me</option>
    <option value="ralf">choose ralf</option>
    <option value="charlie">choose charlie</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/96mgswas/1/

Comment: i can't find documentation for the 'manual' event. what is it?

Comment: `focusin` makes it trigger when the select box is clicked, rather than when an option is selected.

Comment: The focusin also triggers when you use the tab key to "focus" the select.

Comment: "manual" is a custom event I created and trigger when I manually changed the value - see the last line.

Comment: Why trigger a custom invent, why not use `trigger("change")`?

Answer (score 1):

Test the position in the function.

```
$(document).on("change click", "select option", function(e) {
    if ($(this).index() == 0) {
        // do stuff for first child
    } else {
        // do stuff for other children
});
```

However, I don't think the `change` event is fired on `<option>` elements, it just fires on the `<select>` itself. So your basic premise seems to be wrong, because the `change` event would never fire on `select:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: one thing is that it is not the `option` that changes. the `select` changes.

so I guess that means within, we have to do something like `$(this).find(">:first-child").index()` instead.