# Get value of select box on hover or change in same event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry for bad English.How to get value of an select box if user change a select box or just hover on select box with a single event. i have tried this one but its not working

```
jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute]").on('change , hover', function(){
 alert('trigger'); 
});
```

I know we can do like this make separate functions

```
jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute]").on('change', function(){
 alert('trigger'); 
});
```

And

```
jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute]").on('hover', function(){
 alert('trigger'); 
});
```

But i want to do with a single event not separately because i will do same functionality in both cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for comma in event listing, comma is used when you have to apply any action for multiple selector

```
jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute]").on('change mouseover', function(){
  alert('trigger'); 
});
```

If You have to select multiple element then you can use comma like this

```
jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute],#xyz").on('change mouseover', function(){
      alert('trigger'); 
    });
```

Comment: its still not working only change event is working not hover

Comment: try mouseover instead of hover

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma `,` between the event names - they should be separated with a space only.

```
jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute]").on('change mouseover', function(){
  alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute]").on('change mouseover', function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="super_attribute">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: still not working only change is working but not on hover

Comment: @OBAID use mouseover rather hover. And Also se same type of question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to bind elements to multiple events.

1. You can use .on() to bind a function to multiple events.

   ```
   $('#yourelement').on('change mouseover keyup keypress blur', function(e) {
        alert('trigger'); 
   });
   ```
2. define a function like

   ```
   var myFunction = function() {
     alert('trigger'); 
   }
   ```

and pass myFunction as a parameter to event function.

```
$('#yourelement')
.change(myFunction)
.mouseover(myFunction)
.keyup(myFunction)
.keypress(myFunction)
.blur(myFunction)
```

Note: #yourelement is the id of the element to which event to be binded. and call these methods after document ready.

In your case you can either use
    $(function(){

```
    jQuery("select[name*=super_attribute]").on('change mouseover', function(){
     alert('trigger'); 
    });
});
```

or
    $(function(){
        var myFunction = function() {
              alert('trigger'); 
            }

```
$('select[name*=super_attribute]')
    .change(myFunction)
    .mouseover(myFunction);
});
```