# how to create two event for html attribute

Tags: jquery, validation

I would like to create two event by reusing the code of a method, this is my code, how could i able to create two event for single element using jQuery

```
$('#country_ID').on({
    blur : val (),
    submit:val () 
});

function val() {
    if ($('#country_ID').val() == '')
    {
        formval = false;
        alert(formval.toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is as follows:

```
$('#country_ID').bind('blur submit', function (e) {
    // This is your combined function
    val(); //calling the required function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is clear about this, the firs parameter is a list of events

Your case should be like:

```
$('#country_ID').on( "blur submit", val )
```