# How to combine the two events keypress and click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one function, but two events. First event for input and keypress, second event for button and click.

```
  <input class="text">
  <button class="btn">Next</button>
```

And jquery code:

```
        function submit() {
          var inputValue = $( '.text' ).val();
          alert('inputValue');
        };

        $('.btn').on('click', function () {
          submit();
        });
        $('input').keydown(function(e) {
          if(e.which == 13) {
            submit();
          }
        });
```

Can I join these two events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to emulate a `form`'s `submit` event listener.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L2vrf8gd/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this...

```js
    $( '.btn, input' ).on( 'click keydown',  function ( event ) {
        if( ( event.type == 'click' )
            || ( event.type == 'keydown' && event.which  == 13 ) ) {
           //submit(); submit your form
           alert('hi');
        };
    } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="text">
<button class="btn">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.type` - we can determine type event - `click` or `keydown`.

`$(e.target)` - we get `jQuery object`, which was caused by an event.

`e.which != 13` -  determine push `Enter`.

```
$('.btn, input').on('click keydown', function (e) {
    if( (e.type == 'keydown')
         && $(e.target).is('input') 
         && (e.which != 13) ) return; 

    submit();
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Add the same event listener for both the input and the button.

Then, inside the event handler check the type of the event. If the type is `keyup`, check for the correct key. If both satisfies (`keyup` and `which === 13`) you can submit. Otherwise, if the `type` is `click`, you can also submit.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/p33kmbja/1/