# ajax with two events

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to know how add two events in the same ajax

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#department').on('change',function(){
        var deptID = $(this).val(); console.log(deptID);
        if(deptID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: BASE_URL+'User/listHospital',
                data:'id='+deptID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#hospital').html(html);
                    $('#specialisation').html('<option value="">Select hospital</option>');
                         $('#special').html('<option value="">Select hospital</option>');
               }
            }); 
</script>
```

here i had used on change event i want to add one more event on focus what should i do for it please help

Comment: You should check the manual.

Comment: duplicate, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question but, is this how you want it?

```
$("#department").on({

    'change': function(){
          //ajax here
    }

    'focus': function(){
          //ajax here
    }

});
```