# jQuery execute function when input is changed or select is changed

Tags: jquery

I have to change a function. Actually, it executes some lines of code whenever an input field is changed. I need to change the function that it executes whenever an input field has changed a value in a select field is changed. How can I combine this?

My function right now:

```
$("input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
   ....some lines of code
}
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/ Check this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Comment: Also .bind is deprecated, use .on - and .on("input" is a great event handler

Comment: You can use `onchange` event of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
   var DoOnChange=function(){
         console.log($(this).val());
   };
   $("input#inp").on("keyup",DoOnChange);
   $("select#sl").on("change",DoOnChange);
});
```

And if you like using pure js and a legible code, look at code below:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var DoOnChange=function(ev){
      var el=ev.target;
      console.log(el.value);
  };
  document.querySelector("select#sl").addEventListener("change",DoOnChange);
  document.querySelector("input#inp").addEventListener("keyup",DoOnChange);
};
```

Or if you need `change` event:

```
$(function(){
      $("input,select").on("change",function(){
         console.log($(this).val());
     });
});
```

These codes works fine with html code like this:

```
<input type="text" id="inp"/>
<select id="sl">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

I'm typing with my mobile phone and I haven't access to the code tools of `stackoverflow` now, but if you want, you can check the result [online](http://jsbin.com/kudesodiqi/edit?html).