# Binding an existing jQuery function to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger existing jQuery function with click. I been told that this can be done by **.bind**: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

I'm using below code to swipe trought images:

**a**) swipe left = I don't like it

**b**) swipe right = I like it

I want to be able to do exactly the same with clicking on the links.

*.js code:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var likedCount = 0;

    $('.postswiper-post').live('swiperight',function(){
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('rot-left') && !$(this).hasClass('rot-right') ){
            $(this).addClass('rot-left');
            $('.postswiper-post').find('.status').remove();

            $(this).append('<div class="status like">Like!</div>');
            likedCount++;

            var postTitle = $(this).find('.postswiper-posttitle').html();
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-list').append('<div class="postswiper-likedlist-liked">' + postTitle + '</div>');
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-count').text('View my liked items (' + likedCount + ')');

            if ( $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').hasClass('disabled') ) {
                $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
                $('.postswiper-wrapper > p').css('color','inherit');
            }
        }
    });

    //
```

jQuery: https://gist.github.com/edoardoo/89e672f22fa405799fdd

> /*! jQuery Mobile v1.4.5 | Copyright 2010, 2014 jQuery Foundation,
>   Inc. | jquery.org/license */

I have added following html code to my page:

```
<div class="colnew"><a class="click-right" href="/" onclick="return false;">LOVE IT!</a></div>
```

and to *.js file:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var likedCount = 0;

    $('.postswiper-post').live('swiperight',function(){
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('rot-left') && !$(this).hasClass('rot-right') ){
            $(this).addClass('rot-left');
            $('.postswiper-post').find('.status').remove();

            $(this).append('<div class="status like">Like!</div>');
            likedCount++;

            var postTitle = $(this).find('.postswiper-posttitle').html();
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-list').append('<div class="postswiper-likedlist-liked">' + postTitle + '</div>');
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-count').text('View my liked items (' + likedCount + ')');

            if ( $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').hasClass('disabled') ) {
                $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
                $('.postswiper-wrapper > p').css('color','inherit');
            }
        }
    });

//my bind code 

    function fBindFunctionToElement(){
   $('.click-right').bind('swiperight',function(){
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('rot-left') && !$(this).hasClass('rot-right') ){
            $(this).addClass('rot-left');
            $('.postswiper-post').find('.status').remove();

            $(this).append('<div class="status like">Like!</div>');
            likedCount++;

            var postTitle = $(this).find('.postswiper-posttitle').html();
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-list').append('<div class="postswiper-likedlist-liked">' + postTitle + '</div>');
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-count').text('View my liked items (' + likedCount + ')');

            if ( $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').hasClass('disabled') ) {
                $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
                $('.postswiper-wrapper > p').css('color','inherit');
            }
        }
    });
(...)
```

When I click on "LOVE IT" link it doesn't trigger the jQuery function.

**1**. What I'm doing wrong?

**2**. Is there any other way to call existing jQuery function with click?

**Edit**:

The solution below partially solves the problem:

```
$(document).on("click",".click-right",function() { 
if ( !$(this).hasClass('rot-left') && !$(this).hasClass('rot-right') ){
            $(this).addClass('rot-left');
            $('.postswiper-post').find('.status').remove();

            $(this).append('<div class="status like">Like!</div>');
            likedCount++;

            var postTitle = $(this).find('.postswiper-posttitle').html();
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-list').append('<div class="postswiper-likedlist-liked">' + postTitle + '</div>');
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-count').text('View my liked items (' + likedCount + ')');

            if ( $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').hasClass('disabled') ) {
                $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
                $('.postswiper-wrapper > p').css('color','inherit');
            }
        }
    });
```

When I'm clicking on "LOVE IT" this part of the code is triggered

```
$('.postswiper-likedlist-count').text('View my liked items (' + likedCount + ')');
```

but I can't get image to reload same as if I was using mouse swipe. I have a feeling that I forgotten something, something very obvious lol

Comment: You were told incorrectly... .bind doesn't trigger anything.

Comment: You don't appear to be actually calling `fBindFunctionToElement`, so your code never actually does anything.

Comment: @Kevin B Any advice how can I achieve my goal and trigger mentioned jQuery function by clicking on "LOVE IT!" link?

Comment: Start by running the code you've written. Currently it's inside of a function that never gets called.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Both `.bind()` and `.live()` were replaced with `.on()` back in jQuery 1.7...

Comment: @gibberish It's `/*! jQuery Mobile v1.4.5 | Copyright 2010, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */`

Comment: Alright, I'm just guessing about jQuery mobile from my experience with jQuery itself.. Feedback says I'm wrong (-1) so I'll delete my answer -- but see this, perhaps it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Comment: why don't you simply use `$(something).on("click",...)`

Comment: @nazimboudeffa Did that with ```$(document).on("click",".click-right",function()``` but this only partially solved the problem. Function is triggered when link is clicked but I can't get image to reload same as if I was doing swipe by mouse.

Comment: @gibberish Please add your answer again. If no one presents a better way to solve this, I will mark your answer as the most helpful one. Thanks

Comment: @Kris Thanks Kris, done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this (just a WAG...)

Instead of:

```
$('.postswiper-post').live('swiperight',function(){
```

Do:

```
$(document).on('swiperight click', '.postswiper-post', function(){
```

Similarly:

```js
   /*  NON-RUNNING CODE SNIPPET -- For Viewing Only  */
   $(document).on('swiperight click', '.click-right'),function(){
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('rot-left') && !$(this).hasClass('rot-right') ){
            $(this).addClass('rot-left');
            $('.postswiper-post').find('.status').remove();

            $(this).append('<div class="status like">Like!</div>');
            likedCount++;

            var postTitle = $(this).find('.postswiper-posttitle').html();
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-list').append('<div class="postswiper-likedlist-liked">' + postTitle + '</div>');
            $('.postswiper-likedlist-count').text('View my liked items (' + likedCount + ')');

            if ( $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').hasClass('disabled') ) {
                $('.postswiper-likedlist-opener').removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
                $('.postswiper-wrapper > p').css('color','inherit');
            }
        }
    });
```