# How to handle initial state and change of checkbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I need to show/hide div based on checkbox value by jquery:

1. when webpage is loaded **and**
2. when checkbox value is changed (on click/on change)

I found few ways how to solve these problems separately, but does exists a simple way how to handle both group of events at once?

Example (change):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#autoUpdate').show();
        else
            $('#autoUpdate').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked>

<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
    Example
</div>
```

Comment: and do you preset the value of the checkbox or not?

Comment: Yes, sure, it is variable. Otherwise the question wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire the event when the page is loaded:

`$('#checkbox1').change();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').change(function(){
      console.log('fired');
      if(this.checked)
        $('#autoUpdate').show();
      else
        $('#autoUpdate').hide();
    });
    $('#checkbox1').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked>

<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
    Example
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer an alternative, if your elements are siblings, you could do the same logic with CSS, applying a display none to the sibling if a previous sibling is not checked.

```css
#checkbox1:not(:checked) ~ #autoUpdate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked>

<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
  Example
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sure, interesting alternative, I wouldn't think of doing it this way

Comment: @TomasKujal keep in mind it can be considered brittle, given that they need to be siblings.  However, depending upon your UI, this might be all you need.

Answer (score -1):

**[I misread the question, my bad.]**

Use .on() to bind your function to multiple events.

`$('#element').on('click change', function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event fired
});`

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2534089/7416692) for more details.