# Is there an event that is triggered on any event relating to user activity?

Tags: javascript, dom, events

As the title states, I'm seeking to know if there's an event that is fired on any/all user activity?

I'm looking to do something like this

```
<body onanyevent="someFunc()">
...
</body>
```

**someFunc** would run whenever a user does anything on the body of the web page.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need this? There is an easy way to listen with jquery for multiple events. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function (if you think about it, there really isn't much a user can do on a website without moving the mouse or using the keyboard, so listen to any mousemove or keyup/focus on forms is pretty much ALL activity besides staring at the screen)

Comment: Sure. I'm calling a function using setInterval and whenever the user does something, I want to clear that interval and restart. Is that sufficient?

Comment: What do you mean by anytime a user does something? Is moving a mouse something? Is clicking on the page something? How about if the element isn’t interactive? Right clicks? Is hovering a specific element something? Is unhovering something? Are keystrokes something? What if they’re not in a field of any kind? Tell exactly what you’re really trying to solve with this, rather than just how to implement the solution you’ve contrived, and you’ll get better answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want a event whenever a customer clicked an button of the homepage you can use the following code (for example):

```
const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
button1.addEventListener('click', clickedButton);

function clickedButton() {
//do something
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no single event that is fired for any user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

*I'll add my approach to the answers, so it doesn't get lost in the comments:*

**Short answer:** No, there is no single event for user activity.

**Long answer:**

I think the approach here is to define a number of events which are considered "user activity" like mousemove, keyup or focus/blur on formfields and then set up a listener to these events. This can be easily done in jQuery like already explained here:

[jQuery multiple events to trigger the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function)

Depending on the actual page (which we dont know anything about), there could be more events besides mousemove, keyups, focus/blur on all formfields that are considered user-activity. Closing a popup for example.

To listen to more events, check https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Hope this helps.